# React native AndroidPermission don't grant permission

Tags: react-native

hey there i am working with react native project I need to access to the IMIE of the mobile I used react-native-imei everything is fine but the problem the permission doesn't grant here my function

```
getImie = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_STATE,
          {
            title: 'Phone State Permission',
            message:
              'the application needs to access to your phone state to take the IMIE',
            buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            buttonPositive: 'OK',
          },
        );
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          IMEI.getImei().then(imeiList => {
            if (imeiList.length > 0) {
              this.setState({imie: imeiList[0], foundimei: true});
            }
          });
        } else {
          console.log('Phone State permission denied');
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
      }
    }
  };
```

my problem here is the const granted it's an empty string so the get imie function doesn't work and the other crazy thing here I am asking for phone state but the permission is about phone calls like the image bellow

[image]

so can anyone give me any idea about that?

Comment: Have you added the permissions to the `AndroidManifest` file?

Comment: yes I've done in the AndroidManifest